# traversing through a text file multiple times using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to read a text file using javascript and  want to check multiple conditions in that file so the control has to travel multiple times in that text file. Is that possible through javascript?

Comment: In a browser? Where is the text file? http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html

Comment: yes we can browse the text file and load it.

Comment: Well if you can do that then the file contents is in a string, so you can do whatever you like with it.

Answer (score 0):

// Check for the various File API support.
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
  // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
} else {
  alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}

API link ! [API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/)